# Change characters that serve as word separator in KDE?

Tags: kde, keyboard, input-method

I'm running KDE Plasma desktop in Arch Linux.

In GTK-based applications, when I use the Ctrl-arrow shortcut to move a text cursor around words, it stops on underscore characters. *e.g.* If I am in a "Save File" dialog in GTK and my cursor is at the end of `this_character_sequence`, pressing `Ctrl`-`<Left>` will move the cursor to the left of the `s` in `sequence`.

In KDE (for example, Dolphin or any KDE save file dialog), doing the same thing would move the cursor to the very beginning of the sequence, as the `_` is not interpreted as a break between words.

Is this behavior configurable anywhere? I would like my KDE applications to interpret the `_` character as a word break. I've looked around the (extensive) KDE settings, and cannot find anything related.

Comment: I've been annoyed by this for years as well. Apparently there was [a bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416022) about this in 2020-01-08 which indicates that this cannot be adjusted yet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out. I've added a comment to the bug report as well.